# How to remove period after comment in cells of genealogy tree

Tags: genealogytree

I'd like to use genealogytree with a slightly modified "traditional" template (no box around cells).  The slight modification is to allow comments.  My code works, but a period is automatically added right after the comment.  I don't want this period.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{mytree/.style={
    template=database traditional,
    database format=medium no marriage,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \genealogytree[mytree]{
    parent{
      g{name=Son, comment=Prince of the Valley}
      p{name=Father, comment=King of the Hill}
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I prevent the period?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging around in the `grtcore.node.code.tex`, I found an `info separators`-key, that seems to affect it. It is defined as

`\gtrset{info separators={\par}{. }{.}{}}` Removing the second period seems to solve the problem. It's described on page 186 in the [manual](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf)),

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{mytree/.style={
    template=database traditional,
    database format=medium no marriage,
    info separators={\par}{. }{}{}, %<- Removed period from third {} in here
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \genealogytree[mytree]{
    parent{
      g{name=Son, comment=Prince of the Valley}
      p{name=Father, comment=King of the Hill}
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which is described on p186 of the manual.  That's it!

Comment: I tried searching for it, but my chrome PDF-reader was just too slow finding the result. What's up with that?! Anyways: added it to the answer for future TeXers :)